# Is it possible to embed a c++ or java compiler inside Unity 5 scene

Tags: java, c++, unity-game-engine

I'm implementing a game which teaches programming just like robocode and other related applications but I want to implement this game in unity. the user should answer problems by writing his code in the text-area and then compile it, then I should receive his output if there is no error.
Seriously I've searched on google for 3 days and I can't get any answer, it is my graduation project so please I need serious help.

Comment: Embedding a C++ compiler or a JVM seems a complicated task. You'd better write your own interpreter or use something already available which is lightweight (maybe JavaScript or LUA)

Comment: Embedding any language is difficult, but sticking with something commonly integrated already will save you a lot of headache.   Writing the entire program and taking the user input in a single interpreted language will be MUCH easier.  I'm concerned that you took on such an important requirement without understanding the basics of what seems to be a requisite part of the project.

Comment: I just want to know first if there is a way to compile a code the user will be write in the game or not because if there is no way I have to change my idea @xaxxon

Comment: According to the [Unity compatibility documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html) you should be able to access the .NET compiler interface (I never tried this as it is still extremely complicated and I don't consider having players write code a good design).

Comment: @loaymansour yes, there is a way.   If you're using unity, you almost certainly want to use a .net language.

Comment: ok if I am going to use c#, how I can embed or use a compiler to run the user code and receive his output @xaaxxon

Answer (score 1):

Not a Unity expert, but you could get away with calling the compiler as an external program - see [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1108055/execute-external-program.html) example, where they go over how to call a program in a Windows environment.

You'd have to make sure that the compiler is installed and accessible, but other than that things should work.

As a general pattern, this is the way most other programs would access a compiler, rather than including it in their binary.

Comment: you mean that I if I am distributing the application other computers should also have the same compiler that I am working with.

Comment: @loaymansour yup, that's the case. If they're Linux machines it's very likely they already have gcc on them. But if you're on Windows or need another language you'll not have it.

Comment: can I connect to an online compiler for example Ideone.com instead of connecting to an installed program, really I appreciate your help.

Comment: Yup. There's nothing stopping you. More or less. Though you'll need to be sure that the service is available for your users. Would not want Ideone.com to crash or block you while you're doing a thesis presentation.

Comment: yes this point is very important too, thanks very much @horia Comman

Comment: @loaymansour you could also make your own compiling server and connect clients to that.

Comment: wouldnt this be extremely unsafe?